# Angularjs calculation not working on safari on iPad / iPhone

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, safari

I have a calculation in AngularJS which calculates a cost. It works fine in all browsers (that i have tested on) except from Safari on iPads and iPhones.

The calculation looks like this:

```
£ {{ ((((((((height * width) / 1000000) * square_meter_price) + panel_price) * 1)) * (1 + (lookup.dl_markup-0) + (Colours.options.markup-0))) + (lookup.dl_extra_cost-0) + (Colours.options.extra_cost-0) + (hingeholesno * hinge_hole_price)) * panel_quantity | number : 2 }}
```

On safari on iPad / iPhone it displays the above code rather than the cost (overall calculation)

Any ideas on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated as i've searched for hours with no joy.

Comment: Sorry for the not related question, but why do you have such kind of expression in this way? This is unreadable also for a Computer.
Then why do you multiply the first member by 1 * 1 ?

Comment: it works and calculates as it should - just not in safari on iPad / iPhone.

Comment: "It works" is not an answer. Things don't have to work only, but to make sense. And a multiplication by 1, doesn't make sense too much to me with a first looking. 
Then splitting up this calculation you can debug the issue easier and you can unit test it, if you move your code inside the controller and not inline in the HTML

Comment: totally agree with quirimmo, and also I've seen tons of things working in one browser and not in another, just today I posted one answer where Safari and FF wouldn't show chart data correctly but Chrome worked fine with it. And you are talking about devices not just browsers.

Comment: I would recommend move that calculation inside controller/component and bind that resultant variable in  view

Comment: You see code rather than the cost (overall calculation). It mean, that in your page have critical error. That error maybe not produced by your calculation. Try use [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler). Show error in `alert`.

Comment: I'm only seeing the code for the calculation rather than code for the whole page, if that makes sense - away to attempt moving calculation into the controller

Answer (score 0):

i resolved this by using $watch in the controller:

```
    $scope.$watch('((((((((height * width) / 1000000) * square_meter_price) + panel_price) * 1)) * (1 + (lookup.dl_markup-0) + (Colours.options.markup-0))) + (lookup.dl_extra_cost-0) + (Colours.options.extra_cost-0) + (hingeholesno * hinge_hole_price)) * panel_quantity | number : 2', function(fc) {$scope.FullCost = fc;});
```

Then using `{{FullCost}}` in the HTML - it now works and displays in all devices